# DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique. mapping(address=> mapping(address=>uint265)) public allowance;

Tags: solidity, contract

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31JUk.png)

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Tether {
string public name = 'Tether';
string public symbol = 'USDT';
uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000;
uint8 public decimals = 18;

event Transfer(
    address indexed _from,
    address indexed _to,
    uint256 _value
);

event Approval(
    address indexed _owner,
    address indexed _spender,
    uint _value
);
mapping(address=>uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping(address=> mapping(address=>uint265)) public allowance;

constructor() public {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
}

function transfer(address _to,uint256 _value) public returns (bool success){
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender]>= _value);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to]+=_value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}
function approve(address _spender,uint256 _value) public returns(bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] =_value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender,_spender, _value);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
    balanceOf[_to]+=_value;
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;    
}
```

}

i found the error

DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.

mapping(address=> mapping(address=>uint265)) public allowance;

please help me to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely caused by a typo - there's no such thing as `265 bit unsigned integer` (but there is 256 bit).

Replace the `uint265` to `uint256`.